# TeXstudio: How to highlight text in \emph or \textit command, for example?

Tags: highlighting, texstudio

Is there a way to configure TeXstudio so that emphasized text will display in the editor in italics, for example:

> \emph{*some text*}

The custom highlighting seems to apply only to environments or to commands, but does not seem to allow for the highlighting of the text within commands.

This seems strange to me because we can change the font sized and characteristics for text in sectionning commands.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format ;)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change highlighting inside braces of arbitrary commands. Sectioning is an exception which is handled explicitly in the internal parser.

Comment: There is no other way, for example, using a macro?